# Function called three times when in facebook?

Tags: python, facebook

I'm using the following code to add one to two values in case the user wins a challege.

```
def challengewin(request):
    uid = 1313693
    tempuser = User.objects.get(id=uid)
    tempuser.challengeswon = tempuser.challengeswon + 1
    tempuser.silver = tempuser.silver + 1
    tempuser.save()
    return HttpResponse()
```

this works fine if I am working outside the facebook canvas page, inside the canvas page 3 is added instead of 1 everytime. Any Ideas?

Comment: Some context would be useful here. What framework are you using? What calls the code? Where does it run?

Comment: I am using python/django running on apache. This simply increases the value of two variables when triggered.

Outside facebook canvas page it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the code you have included is not the culprit.

Have you confirmed that `challengewin(request);` is not being called 3 times?

Comment: Under normal circumstances its called just once, but when I put it in facebook canvas page ( even in url) and press enter its called three times.